# Query to retrieve the cheapest price and Package description

Tags: sql-server

Good afternoon,

I have a question: I want to retrieve a list that will give me the cheapest price + package description for each product_id.

I have a query, but this returns all the packages with the cheapest price.

this is the query I created:

```
select p.Product_ID, vp.verpakking_omschrijving, lowprice
from VerpakkingProduct vp
inner join Product p
on vp.Product_ID=p.Product_ID
inner join(
select p.product_id, min(vw.prijs) as lowprice from Product P
inner join VerpakkingProduct vp
on p.Product_ID=vp.Product_ID
inner join VerpakkingWinkel vw
on vp.Verpakking_ID=vw.Verpakking_ID
group by p.Product_ID) as prijslijst on prijslijst.Product_ID=p.Product_ID
inner join VerpakkingWinkel vw 
on vw.Verpakking_ID=vp.Verpakking_ID and vw.prijs=prijslijst.lowprice
```

The query to retrieve the lowest price for each product_id is correct.
Additionally I want to add the package description (Verpakking_omschrijving) for the lowest price of each product_id. 
Can someone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: The problem is that some of the packages have the same price. Therefore both packages are in the list. How can I make sure I only get one of the packages?

Comment: How would you choose which of the packages to display and which one not to?

Answer (score 0):

Use below query. This will return only one product.

```
select MIN(p.product_id), min(vw.prijs) as lowprice 
from Product P
inner join VerpakkingProduct vp on p.Product_ID=vp.Product_ID
inner join VerpakkingWinkel vw on vp.Verpakking_ID=vw.Verpakking_ID
group by p.Product_ID
```